# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create unknown attribute: user_id

Tags: ruby, devise, registration, controllers

I get the error above when trying to sign up for an account.  I am using Devise and trying to add profile after a person signs up.  How do I fix this error so user can sign up and make their profile?  I also want to add an avatar to the profile along with additional fields like address, phone number, etc. Here are my files:

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
 end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profiles_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    profiles_path(resource)
  end
end
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user 

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 

  has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true

    has_one :profile
  before_create :build_profile #creates profile at user registration
end
```

routes.rb

```
'Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :profiles

  resources :pins
  devise_for :users



  #devise_for :installs
  root "pins#index"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140818034852) do

  create_table "installs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "installs", ["email"], name: "index_installs_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "installs", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_installs_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "pins", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "pins", ["user_id"], name: "index_pins_on_user_id"

  create_table "profiles", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "user_profiles", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your schema.rb, it's missing user_id. So what you need to do is run the following

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_profile
```

This will help associate the profile model with the user model.